# Recreate ElasticSearch Index with Nest 7.x

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to be able to recreate an ElasticSearch index, in production, without any downtime.

With previous versions of Nest (5 and earlier) it was possible to do that by having an alias that points at your original index, creating a new index, updating the alias to point to the new index, and then dropping the original index.

Is it possible to achieve something similar, without downtime, with Nest 7.x?  If so, how.  If you can provide an example with Object Initializer Syntax, that would be most helpful.

Comment: Could you share your NEST 5.x code? I think it's still possible maybe some methods were moved.

Comment: @Rob I don't have NEST 5.x code - I was referring to the official NEST documentation you could find here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/aliasing.html

Answer (score 3):

Please find an example with comments below

```
//first we create base index
var createIndexResponse = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index1");

//and we create alias to it
var putAliasResponse = await client.Indices.PutAliasAsync(new PutAliasRequest("index1", "index"));

//next step is to create a new index
var createIndexResponse2 = await client.Indices.CreateAsync("index2");

//and create bulk operation to remove alias to index1 and create alias to index2
await client.Indices.BulkAliasAsync(new BulkAliasRequest
{
    Actions = new List<IAliasAction>
    {
        new AliasRemoveAction {Remove = new AliasRemoveOperation {Index = "index1", Alias = "index"}},
        new AliasAddAction {Add = new AliasAddOperation {Index = "index2", Alias = "index"}}
    }
});

System.Console.WriteLine("Indices pointing to alias:");
foreach (var index in await client.GetIndicesPointingToAliasAsync("index"))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Output:

```
Indices pointing to alias:
index2
```

Hope that helps.