# ElasticSearch NEST recreate index with zero downtime

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am writing backend in C# for a website. I'd like to recreate index with little downtime.
After reading these two posts:
[Nest Client c# 7.0 for elastic search removing Aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58291005/nest-client-c-sharp-7-0-for-elastic-search-removing-aliases)
[Recreate ElasticSearch Index with Nest 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929255/recreate-elasticsearch-index-with-nest-7-x)

I come up with this:

```
                    var alias_exist = await _client.Indices.ExistsAsync(index_string_alias);
                    if (alias_exist.Exists)
                    {
                        var oldIndices = await _client.GetIndicesPointingToAliasAsync(index_string_alias);
                        var oldIndexName = oldIndices.First().ToString();

                        await _client.Indices.BulkAliasAsync(new BulkAliasRequest
                        {
                            Actions = new List<IAliasAction>
                            {
                                new AliasRemoveAction {Remove = new AliasRemoveOperation {Index = oldIndexName, Alias = index_string_alias}},
                                new AliasAddAction {Add = new AliasAddOperation {Index = index_string_unique, Alias = index_string_alias}}
                            }
                        });
                    } else
                    {
                        var putAliasResponse = await _client.Indices.PutAliasAsync(new PutAliasRequest(index_string_unique, index_string_alias));
                    }
                }
```

I'd like to remove index_string_alias if exists and assign the alias to the newly created index_string_unique.

Also, I'd like to confirm that I can treat the alias as the index name in my other queries.

I am really new to Elastic Search and wonder how people figure out these things. I searched through the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html) and found little information about the async functions in NEST. Where should I look for explanations for functions?

Comment: Each client API has an XML comment on it that points to the Elasticsearch API, including a link to the documentation

Comment: That's true, but it seems the link points to RESTful API. I need documentation for NEST that explains different function calls. For example, I'd like to learn about client.Indices.BulkAliasAsync()

Comment: The client is an implementation that calls the REST APIs. As an example,  `BulkAliasAsync()` is an async method that calls `/_aliases` endpoint: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html. What do you feel is missing in the Elasticsearch documentation - C# examples, something else/more?

Comment: C# examples and parameter lists. For me, it's not clear how to call functions like BulkAliasAsync() using NEST. I need guidance on how to translate CRUD API calls to NEST function calls.